# Adding a subview like UISlider or UIButtom in Google Maps in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am new to iOS Programming and have very little knowledge about COCOA Touch. I am trying to add a button on the screen at the bottom over Google maps for giving an option to the user to go back to the previous screen. I just know that `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView` and we can make button appear on a view by making it the sub view of that class. Previously iOS used to use Google Maps by default by in `MKMapView` and I have seen examples in books an on the Internet showing screen shots of apps where a button or a text box would appear on the map. But now just dragging the button in the interface builder doesn't help.

[image: Text box over MKMapView]

Here is my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;


@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loadView
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //Latitude and longitude of the current location of the device.
    double lati = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    double longi = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", lati);
    NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", longi);

    CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lati longitude:longi];

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the coordinate

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lati
                                                            longitude:longi
                                                                 zoom:11.5];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lati, longi);
    marker.title = @"It's Me";
    marker.snippet = @"My Location";
    marker.map = mapView_;

    [mapView_ addSubview:_btn];
    [mapView_ bringSubviewToFront:_btn];

}

@end
```

Please let me know how it can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: google maps and MKMapView are not related and have a diffent feature set / follow a different approach

Comment: but .. just make the slider a subview of the map. would work fine with MKMapView

Comment: I know it would work fine with MKMapView. But As far as I know MKMapView wouldn't give me Google Maps. It will give me the maps provided by Apple. That Is my real problem.

Comment: A view is a view is a view. What goes wrong when you drag a UISlider onto the Google Map view?

Comment: @Craig
I declared a mapView for google map in the following manner
    **mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;**
and made a button *btn as the subview of mapview_.
    **[mapView_ addSubview:_btn];
    [mapView_ bringSubviewToFront:_btn];**

But still it is not visible on the screen

Comment: Have you done the same with any other visual element? Does the map appear? Does the button appear if you use an MKMapView?

Comment: Yes it does appear for MKMapView..

Answer (score 6):

Do normal UI building on your current view, then add the `GMSMapView` as `subview` (at `index` 0) of the `self.view` (DON'T do `self.view = mapView;`)

Here is the significant code:

```
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
```

Inserting the map view at `index` 0 will set the rest of the objects in front.

Comment: I added the code suggested by you in my program. But when I ran the program and clicked on the button in my application to go to the map view the application hung and didn't load the next screen where map should have appeared.
So I again went back to the old code - `self.view = mapView_`

Comment: Would you send your code to see where the problem is? Oh make sure to put the code above in viewDidLoad method, not loadView.

Comment: This approach doesn't work.  The GMSMapView simply does not appear.

Comment: FYI in swift: self.view.insertSubview(view, at: 0)

Answer (score 1):

i suggest creating your button programmatically not using storyBoard, i tested this on "Google Maps SDK version: 1.4.0.4450" and it worked.

```
UIButton *button    = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame        = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40);
[button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.279526
                                                        longitude:-96.987305
                                                             zoom:2];

self.mapView    = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];;
self.view       = self.mapView;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: My purpose of asking this question was to go to the previous screen basically. So I solved my problem by displaying the map by embedding it into a Navigation controller. But the only disadvantage is that the Navigation bar would eat up some space of the screen even though I am interested in only a small button to do the needful.